# How can I evaluate a concatenated string as a formula?

Tags: excel, formula

I used `CONCATENATE()` to generate multiple formulas as text for a range of week numbers.
When I copy the formulas into a cell, I see the formula text and not the calculated values.

How do I copy it in a way that it shows the formula result, and not the formula text?

Comment: This is almost certainly not the best or easiest way to proceed. Please show us an example of the formulas you generate this way, so we can suggest better alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

create a user defined function

```
Public Function eval(concatstr)
eval = Worksheet.Evaluate(concatstr)
End Function
```

then put this in the target cell

```
=eval(A1&B1&C1)
```

where a1, b1 and c1 are the values to be concatenated this concatenates the string and evaluates it in a single cell

or

```
=eval(D1)
```

where D1 is the concatenated string